# Google Nearby connections - Not able to transfer large bytes between 2 devices

Tags: stream, google-nearby

When I try to send an object with multiple images(converted to string using Base64) as STREAM type, from the onPayloadTransferUpdate() method, I can see "Failure" result and the devices(tested only when 2 devices are connected) automatically disconnect after that. Is Google Nearby connections not the right option to send large bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Nearby Connections should be able to handle that. There's no explicit size limit on STREAM payloads.

I would suggest chunking the bytes (eg. send a couple KB at a time) and seeing if that helps. You can get into weird situations when you send entire files at once because it loads the bytes into memory twice (once inside your app, and once inside the Nearby process) which can cause out of memory errors. Binder, the interprocess communication layer on Android, also has a limited buffer to send data between processes.

You can also save it as a temporary file and send it as a FILE payload, in which case we will handle the chunking for you.

Disclaimer: I work on Nearby Connections.

Comment: ok, thanks. Actually, when I use P2P_STAR stratergy, the transfer works perfectly for any size. For my application I just need 1-1 communication at any moment so going with P2P_STAR as it resolves my issue!

Comment: Sounds like the transfer was just taking a very long time, and the faster speeds on STAR helped out. Consider using POINT_TO_POINT, if you only need 1 connection at a time.

Comment: @Xlythe Could you theoretically send a 20 gigbyte file over Nearby Connections?

Comment: Yes, 20GB should be fine. You'll likely want to handle a way to resume an interrupted transfer, but otherwise it should just work. If you set up a new Pixel phone, for instance, it uses Nearby Connections to exchange up to 50GB of old photos, videos, and apps.

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need to Base64-encode the data for the sake of Nearby Connections -- your STREAM can have raw binary data, and that'll work just fine.

2) How big is this data you're sending, and at what byte offset (you can see this in the [PayloadTransferUpdate](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data#progress_updates) you get with Status.ERROR) does it fail at? It sounds like your devices are just getting disconnected.

3) What [Strategy](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/strategies) are you using?

4) If you still have discovery ongoing (i.e. you haven't called stopDiscovery()), try stopping that and then sending your Payload -- discovery is a heavyweight operation that can make it hard to reliably maintain connections between devices for long intervals.

Comment: For my application, it is easy to work with Base64 encoding, so used that. Secondly, the data I'm trying to send is almost 20MB, for stream type it does not show the total size, rather shows "-1". I used P2P_CLUSTER stratergy. Once the connection has been established I stop both advertising and discovery. However, the easy solution was converting it P2P_STAR topology, all transfer works perfectly when I use this one. Since I need 1-1 communication at anytime, I'm going with this solution

Comment: Thanks for getting back with answers to my questions, Karthik.

The total size for a STREAM is always -1 because we cannot always know the total size of data that is being streamed (potentially) live, but FYI, you can get [the number of bytes that have been transferred til now](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/PayloadTransferUpdate.html#getBytesTransferred()).

@Xlythe said everything else I was going to say about using P2P_POINT_TO_POINT in his comment below, so definitely consider using that. :)